# Mongo DB - map relational data to document structure

Tags: mongodb

I have a dataset containing 30 million rows in a mongo collection. An example set of records would be:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("568bc0f2f7cd2653e163a9e4"),    
"EmailAddress" : "1234@ab.com",    
"FlightNumber" : 1043,
"FlightTime" : "10:00"},
{"_id" : ObjectId("568bc0f2f7cd2653e163a9e5"),    
"EmailAddress" : "1234@ab.com",    
"FlightNumber" : 1045,
"FlightTime" : "12:00"},
{"_id" : ObjectId("568bc0f2f7cd2653e163a9e6"),    
"EmailAddress" : "5678@ab.com",    
"FlightNumber" : 1045,
"FlightTime" : "12:00"},
```

This has been imported directly from SQL server, hence the relational'esque nature of the data.

How can I best map this data to another collection so that all the data is then grouped by EmailAddress with the FlightNumbers nested? An example of the output would then be:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("can be new id"),    
"EmailAddress" : "1234@ab.com",    
"Flights" : [{"Number":1043, "Time":"10:00"},{"Number":1045, "Time":"12:00"}]},    
{"_id" : ObjectId("can be new id"),    
"EmailAddress" : "5678@ab.com",    
"Flights" : [{"Number":1045, "Time":"12:00"}]},
```

I've been working on an import routing that iterates through each record in the source collection and then bulk inserts into the second collection. This is working fine however doesn't allow me to group the data unless I back process through the records which adds a huge time overhead to the import routine.

The code for this would be:

```
var sourceDb = db.getSiblingDB("collectionSource");
var destinationDb = db.getSiblingDB("collectionDestination");

var externalUsers=sourceDb.CRM.find();
var index = 0; 
var contactArray = new Array();
var identifierArray = new Array();

externalUsers.forEach(function(doc) {    
    //library code for NewGuid omitted
    var guid = NewGuid();
    //buildContact and buildIdentifier simply create 2 js objects based on the parameters
    contactArray.push(buildContact(guid, doc.EmailAddress, doc.FlightNumber));
    identifierArray.push(buildIdentifier(guid, doc.EmailAddress));

    index++;

    if (index % 1000 == 0) {         
        var now = new Date();
        var dif = now.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        var Seconds_from_T1_to_T2 = dif / 1000;
        var Seconds_Between_Dates = Math.abs(Seconds_from_T1_to_T2);
        print("Written " + index + " items (" + Seconds_Between_Dates + "s from start)");    
    }    

    //bulk insert in batches
    if (index % 5000 == 0) {    
        destinationDb.Contacts.insert(contactArray);
        destinationDb.Identifiers.insert(identifierArray);

        contactArray = new Array();
        identifierArray = new Array();
    } 
});
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hey there and welcome to MongoDB. In this situation you may want to consider using two different Collections -- one for users and one for flights.

User:

```
{
    _id: 
    email:
}
```

Flight:

```
{
    _id:
    userId:
    number: // if number is unique, you can actually specify _id as number
    time:
}
```

In your forEach loop, you would first check to see if a user document with that specific email address already exists. If it doesn't, create it. Then use the User document's unique identifier to insert a new document into the Flights collection, storing the identifier under the field `userId` (or maybe `passengerId`?).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The scope of the import is to prime data for another application that maps the collection to c# dto's and one unfortunate restriction about this process is we have users, with nested facets (ie the flights). I could redo the logic of the loop to cross reference each row but worry it would really slow down the import. It does feel a close problem to something aggregation would solve, just not sure the best approach.

Comment: That's a pretty debilitating restriction! Unfortunately I can't speak to exporting the data from MongoDB; I just know how I would want that information represented in MongoDB.